# Feature request: add a link to /search on the header

Tags: feature-request, search, hyperlinks

**EDIT**: I specifically meant on mobile web. Although now that I'm looking again I see that if you click on `Questions` then there is a faint magnifying glass to the right of the word "Questions" that opens search on tap.

---

As far as I can tell, the only way get to StackOverflow's search function is URL hacking, or searching it.

It would be lovely to just have a magnifying glass next to my inbox and the little graph icon.

Comment: There's a big white box at the very top of every page. Isn't that enough?

Comment: Search is integrated in every page. Just use the box at the top / click the magnifying glass on smaller screens.

Comment: I am on mobile. There is the looking Glass icon that does you want, I think.

Comment: If you were unable to find the search icon in the mobile view, then this is a serious UX problem. It's there; I use it all the time. But if users can't find it, then it might as well not exist. (And would explain a lot...)

Answer (score 6):

Feature is instantly implemented per your request: there is a huge search box right above the title for desktop view and magnifying glass icon on mobile view.

[image]